# crontab logs command not found

Tags: cron, centos7

I have a crontab

```
50 11 * * * root /home/user/web/domain.com/python/stepn/cron.sh >> /home/user/web/domain.com/python/stepn/cronlogs.log 2>&1
```

the contents of cron.sh are

```
/home/user/web/domain.com/python/stepn/venv/bin/python /home/user/web/domain.com/python/stepn/get.py
```

the sh file works from the command line. Whenever the cron runs the log file contains

```
/bin/bash: root: command not found
```

the -R permissions on the stepn folder are user:wheel

I changed the group to wheel so that root had permissions to the folder. I don't know if I needed to so that. Previously it was user:user

I notice the python is a shortcut to /opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/bin/python

I don't know what else to try, to get the cron to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where exactly you define your crontab entries, the user column (in your case set to `root`) is not expected and supported.

This is for example the case when editing your crontabs using the `crontab -e` command. Here, the user which should run the command is implicitly set to the user whose crontab you are editing.

In your case, cron does not expect a username after the time specification and thus assumes that it should run the following command:

```
root /home/user/web/domain.com/python/stepn/cron.sh >> /home/user/web/domain.com/python/stepn/cronlogs.log 2>&1
```

As you don't have an executable named `root`, this fails. To fix this, make sure you define your crontab entry in the right context and/or get rid of the user name specification there if the user is implied.

Comment: I'm using crontab -e logged in as root but the files are all in the home area of user. I added root because I previously had the error "ERROR (getpwnam() failed)"  in the crontab status. should I change root to user in the crontab?

Comment: I figured out what you meant. Originally i was editing /etc/crontab and thats when I had the getpwnam error, after reading some webpages I switched to crontab -e and added the root.  I've taken away the root and now it works.